# Selenium WebDriver: Setting date on date picker

Tags: automated-testing, selenium-webdriver

I am automating a web application which has multiple `date pickers` in them. I am sending values in them by using `javascriptExecutor`.

```
IJavaScriptExecutor js = (IJavaScript)driver; 
string jscript = (string)js.ExecuteScript("document.getElementById('formSIES:cFechaIniSintomas_input').removeAttribute('readonly',0);");
```

The problem is that my code does not work in all my date pickers. I have tried with another script

```
IJavaScriptExecutor js = (IJavaScript)driver; 
string jscript = (string)js.ExecuteScript(document.getElementById('formSIES:cFechaIniSintomas_input').setAttribute('value','11/12/2018'););
```

I went over the format and it is correct. Please check.

Comment: Can you post the error(s) that you are seeing?  As it is, your code is a bit too nebulous to help you effectively.

Comment: I just use sendkeys - when testing, usually the point is to test the overal function of the process, not the already developer unit-tested (a billion times) datepicker itself.

Comment: Technically I am not having a  problem, but the value send by my date picker is not the one I am sending in the JavascriptExecutor. It picks today's date instead of my value

Comment: Could share the HTML of the datepicker? Probably is more reliable to simulate the user interaction, such as finding the date using findElement based on a string.

Answer (score 0):

You can try this

String dateval = "28/03/2019";

selectDatebyJs(driver, date1, dateval);
    }

public void selectDatebyJs(WebDriver driver,WebElement element, String dateval) throws InterruptedException
    {

JavascriptExecutor js = ((JavascriptExecutor) driver);
        js.executeScript("arguments[0].setAttribute('value','"+dateval+"');", element);
        WebElement date2= driver.findElement(By.id("yourId"));